# NSURLRequest directory listing parse

Tags: ios, ftp, nsurlrequest

I create an NSURLRequest and an NSURLConnection object and collect data in an NSMutableData instance. I then create an NSString from the downloaded data and get the directory listing of an ftp server that looks something like this:

```
drwx--x--x   13 username   username         4096 Feb  5 17:43 .
drwx--x--x   13 username   username         4096 Feb  5 17:43 ..
drwxr-x---   14 username   99               4096 Feb  1 16:55 public_html
```

I'm guessing there is some standard way of parsing this data, but I have had no luck on google.

So my question is, what is the best way of getting this data into some manageable object?

Comment: You mean NSURLConnection? NSConnection is a different class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use NSScanner to chop up the string. That's probably the easiest option.

Alternatively, if those are tabs separating the values, you could split it up using the `componentsSeparatedByString:` method of NSString (which returns an array), and just do it in several nested loops. So first split it by @"\n", then split each line by @"\t", and so on.

Or if the spacing of the values in each line is always consistent, you could grab each value using the `substringWithRange:` method of NSString.

Or, if you're comfortable with regular expressions, NSRegularExpression is another option.